# Поиск по нескольким словам не работает почему

Tags: php

делаю поиск. Все работает если только одно слово указать, а если несколько через пробел, то не ищет. Не подскажите, в чем дело?

```
<?php
  function connectDatabase($host = 'localhost', $user = 'root', $password = '', $db_name = 'food') {
    return new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $user, $password);
  }

 function search($search_word) {
  $link = connectDatabase();

  $is_email_exist = $link->prepare("SELECT `id`, `photo_path`, `owner_id`, `timestamp_created`, `title`, `description` FROM `food` WHERE `title` LIKE :search_text");

  $is_email_exist->execute(array(':search_text' => '%'.$search_word.'%'));

  $arr = array();

  while($row1 = $is_email_exist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $arr[] = $row1;
  }
  return $arr;
}
var_dump(search('test'));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы это работало корректно, нужно для каждого слова писать `column LIKE '%WORD%'`

Во-первых надо разбить строку на пробелы (использовать `explode()`)

Во-вторых надо сформировать строку `column1 LIKE ? OR column1 LIKE ? OR column2 LIKE ?` по количеству элементов в массиве (использовать `str_repeat`)

А потом подставить массив в запрос, типа

```
$query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE ? OR column1 LIKE ? OR column2 LIKE ?');
$query->execute(array("%$word1%","%$word1%",.....));
```

Используя массив из разбитых слов, в которые добавлены проценты

```
$string = 'test test2 test3';
$explodedArr = explode(' ', $string);
$mappedArr = array_map(function($item) {
    return "%{$item}%";
}, $explodedArr);

print_r($mappedArr);

Array
(
    [0] => %test%
    [1] => %test2%
    [2] => %test3%
)
```